# How to change boot partition for Beaglebone Black after flashing Debian 8.4 to eMMC?

Tags: linux, boot, beagleboneblack, partition, u-boot

I'm trying to get [the current Debian 8.4 SD card image](https://debian.beagleboard.org/images/bone-debian-8.4-lxqt-4gb-armhf-2016-05-13-4gb.img.xz) onto my Beaglebone Black's eMMC. The flashing itself worked flawlessly by enabling (uncommenting) this line in the `/boot/uEnv.txt` file:

```
cmdline=init=/opt/scripts/tools/eMMC/init-eMMC-flasher-v3.sh
```

Flashing completed successfully with blinking LED's as described in the HowTo. Next, I connected a serial-USB cable to the J1 connector in order to see the boot process in Putty's serial console. The system starts to boot but then stops with an error message:

```
Begin: Waiting for root file system ... Begin: Running /scripts/local-block ... done.
Begin: Running /scripts/local-block ... done.
[line above repeats multiple times]
Begin: Running /scripts/local-block ... done.
done.
Gave up waiting for root device.  Common problems:
 - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
   - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
   - Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
 - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT!  /dev/mmcblk1p1 does not exist.  Dropping to a shell!
```

I then get an `(initramfs)` prompt. From there, I figured out that `mmcblk1p1` is not the right partition, it should be `mmcblk0p1` instead. I think this is because of a different enumeration when the SD card is removed.

Now the big question: How and where can I set the partition the system starts from? It must be defined somewhere. I can mount the root partition mmcblk0p1 and edit files from the prompt, so I hope that there's just a small config file I need to tweak. Do I need to add something to the /boot/uEnv.txt file? (I already commented out the flasher script after flashing, of course).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

It should be as easy as editing `uEnv.txt`.

There should be a line containing: `root=/dev/mmcblk1p1` - just edit that to say `/dev/mmcblk0p1`.

Comment: There was no such line, that's the thing... I tried adding it like you wrote, I also tried "mmcroot" and "rootfs" instead of "root", but it didn't change anything.

Comment: I'll have to flash one of my Beaglebones with a recent image to give you a better answer. The above was my best guess based on the old layout. Is there by any chance a FAT partition on the eMMC? If yes, check if that has a uEnv.txt

Comment: Did you find a way to do this, I'm also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

The current version of the flasher script (Dec 2019) changes the boot designation to eMMC automagically upon successful completion of the flash.